# Issue adding roles to Discord members programmatically

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've got an issue when trying to add a role to a member programmatically. `member.roles.add` is throwing **the following error**:

```
(node:9420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

I'd tried to pass in the `id` and `name` of the role to the `add` method but this did not work either. What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**Below is the functionality to apply the role itself (within its context) for better understanding of my issue:**

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content.match(/[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/)) {
        if((msg.content.match((new RegExp(/[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/, "g")) || []).length) >= 30) {
            msg.channel.send(`${"<@" + msg.author.id + ">"}. Your message has been deleted for containing too many special characters.`);
            
            const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID_HERE);
            let mute_role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'spammer');
            var member = guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id);

            member.roles.add(mute_role);
            msg.delete();
        }
    }
   ...
```

Comment: Most likely `mute_role` is `undefined` because there isn't a role called `spammer` in the guild, or Discord.js hasn't cached that role.

Comment: When I `console.log(mute_role)` it definitely exists, the array contains the `id`, `name` etc.

Comment: Any chance var ```member``` is undefined? Instead of this complex chain, you can obtain the member object of the author by just ```msg.member```. This also aplies to const ```guild```, which for some reason was used correctly in ```mute_roles```, as ```msg.guild```.

Comment: Try this:

```msg.reply(`Your message has been deleted for containing too many special characters.`);
msg.delete();

const role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.localeCompare('spammer', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0);

msg.member.roles.add(role);```